# The difference between QAPlug-CheckStyle and CheckStyle-IDEA

Tags: checkstyle, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

Found a similar question about the difference between QAPlug-FindBugs and FindBugs-IDEA, but not about CheckStyle...

I think (from previous experience) with these plug-ins that one difference is that the QAPlug's CheckStyle version seems to be behind the CheckStyle-IDEA's CheckStyle version (I'm not referring to the versions of the plug-ins, but of the version of CheckStyle that's embedded in them).

Anyone knows of any other differences between those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Advantages of CheckStyle-IDEA over QAPlug – Checkstyle:

- Newer version of Checkstyle used
- Community on [GitHub](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea)
- [Fast scan before commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZzmK.png)
- Support for multiple configurations
- Support for third-party checks

I haven't noticed any use case when QAPlug is better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to pretty much nail it :)