# Checkstyle regexp not working for annotated lines?

Tags: regex, annotations, checkstyle

I try to configure a Checkstyle rule to show me Tests marked with a specific TestGroup named FIXME to identify how many of such tests there are (to keep them tracked).

A typical test method looks like this:

```
@Test(groups = {TestGroups.GAMEHISTORY, TestGroups.FIXME}, description = "Some descriptive text...")
public void navigateThroughGameHistory() throws Exception {
    PlayerDTO player = ghHelper.createConfirmedPlayerAndPayIn(TestBase.LANGUAGE);
    ... some more code ...
}
```

I tried my very best with various CheckStyle rules (RegExp with Single & Multiline, RegExpJava etc.), but it seems the Checkstyle does not parse lines containing annotations. 
The simplest way to find an occurrence of FIXME to me seems the following:

```
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="format" value=".*FIXME.*"/>
    <property name="illegalPattern" value="true"/>
    <property name="duplicateLimit" value="-1"/>
    <property name="errorLimit" value="100"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="false"/>
    <property name="message" value="Keep track of the FIXME-Tests!"/>
</module>
```

However, this does not work. However, if I change the format line to

```
    <property name="format" value=".*player.*"/>
```

, I get one occurrence. I believe Checkstyle doesn't check Annotated Lines of Code by default - but I could not find any evidence for it.

But maybe my RegEx is just incorrect (simple as it is)?

I am desperate, because I am sure there is a simple solution, but I just can't find it..

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance, 
Jan

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When running Checkstyle on your example from command line I get:

    `java -jar checkstyle-6.5-all.jar -c config.xml TestClass.java  
    Starting audit...  
    TestClass.java:3: warning: Line matches the illegal pattern 'Keep track of the FIXME-Tests!'.  
    Audit done.`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply - I tried from the command line as well and indeed it does work! However, from inside IntelliJ IDEA using the QAplug-CheckStyle Plugin, it still does not work... Any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't think QAplug-CheckStyle Plugin is still maintained. Have you tried CheckStyle-IDEA? Please see my response to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117754/the-difference-between-qaplug-checkstyle-and-checkstyle-idea/